# Cabeceras de seguridad en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, googlepagespeed

He realizado un escaneo de seguridad en la web https://securityheaders.com/, y me ha dado que las siguientes cabeceras de seguridad no están presentes:

- Strict-Transport-Security
- X-Frame-Options
- X-Content-Type-Options
- Referrer-Policy
- Permissions-Policy

Debido a esto la puntuación que he obtenido es D, y me recomienda subsanarlo añadiendo los códigos en el archivo .htaccess, cosa que no me gusta demasiado tocar salvo que sea necesario.
La duda que me surge es si estas cabeceras son realmente necesarias para el buen funcionamiento y posicionamiento de la web. ¿Afectan al SEO y a la puntuación de Pagespeed?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a responder en base a mi experiencia.

Yo no he visto afectado el SEO de mis webs y tampoco he visto mayor impacto en PageSpeed o Lighthouse. Las siguientes líneas me las ha puesto el Firewall que tengo comprado, Sucuri.

```
# OCHOA Sucuri Security
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

Pero yo tengo otras en la parte de Seguridad, me gusta tener todo cubierto.

```
# OCHOA
# Protect wp-config.php
<files wp-config.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</files>
#Protect error_log
<files error_log>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
#Protect xmlrpc.php
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
#Protect readme.html
<Files readme.html>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN block author scans
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (author=\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
# END block author scans
# OCHOA
```

Y como repito, en mi caso me gusta cubrir todo, tengo bloqueada la API solo para sesiones activas, archivos de configs, el XMLRPC, los CronJobs de WP, los Hertbeats, Ediciones de archivos, en fin, no me gusta dejar cosas sin proteger.

También tengo un log propio que me captura algunos intentos de IPs que buscan lo que no deben

```
25/11/2023 06:32:31 - 82.163.176.123 - United Kingdom -  - GET - /wp-admin/user/network.php
```

Luego bloqueo esas IPs y bueno, al mes, es poco los intentos de vulneración que tengo, muy pocos y sin ningún significado relevante.